# I have a error with create trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I want to create a trigger after insert new record it should capture new record information.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_AccountInsert
ON [dbo].[Accounts]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewValue NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @CompanyName NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @ContactPhone NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @Status bit;
    DECLARE @OtherId int;

    SELECT @OtherId = i.AccountId FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @name = i.Name FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @CompanyName = i.CompanyName FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @ContactPhone = i.ContactPhone FROM inserted i;    
    SELECT @Status = i.[Status] FROM inserted i;

    SET @NewValue = N'[{
            "Name" : ' + @Name +',
            "CompanyDetails" : '+ @CompanyName +',
            "ContactPhone" : '+ @ContactPhone + ',
            "Status" : '+ @Status + '
        }]';

    PRINT @NewValue

    INSERT INTO Auditlog (OtherId, TableName, ActionDate, ActionBy, Operation, ActionType) 
    VALUES (@OtherId, 'Accounts', getdate(), '', 'Insert', 'Accounts');

    DECLARE @AuditlogId int;
    SET @AuditlogId = IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Auditlog') ;

    INSERT INTO AuditlogDetails (AuditlogId, OldValue, NewValue) 
    VALUES (@AuditlogId, null, @NewValue);
END
```

but I get an error :

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_AccountInsert, Line 79
>   The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add operator.

Please help me fix this error

Comment: The error message clearly tells what's happending. Status is bit, you need to convert it to nvarchar in "set @NewValue = ...." statement

Comment: can i use this CAST( @Status as NVARCHAR(10))

Comment: not necessary convert to nvarchar(10), nvarchar is longer enough for bit.

Comment: Don't do this. Your trigger is fundamentally flawed. It's easy to insert multiple rows at a time, and then your trigger will not do what you think it does.

Comment: sr but can you help me my @NewValue inserted is Null

Comment: If you are inserting multiple lines on batch, It is possible, you will lost some data.

Comment: can you write for me a example with if @name != null or != empty
then i add in NewValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you.. Simplified & will work for Multiple inserts at a time.

**Note:** Schema I assumed only from your code and not tested because I don't have schema & data with me.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_AccountInsert
ON [dbo].[Accounts]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Auditlog (OtherId, TableName, ActionDate, ActionBy, Operation, ActionType)
        SELECT 
            i.AccountId, 'Accounts', getdate(), '', 'Insert', 'Accounts' 
        FROM 
            inserted i

    /*  --As per comments updated new insert below
    INSERT INTO AuditlogDetails (AuditlogId, OldValue, NewValue)
        SELECT 
            A.AuditlogId, NULL, N'[{
                "Name" : ' + ISNULL(i.NAME,'') +',
                "CompanyDetails" : '+ ISNULL(I.CompanyName,'') +',
                "ContactPhone" : '+ ISNULL(I.ContactPhone,'') + ',
                "Status" : '+ISNULL( CAST(i.[Status] AS VARCHAR(5)),'')+ '
              }]' 
        FROM 
            inserted i
        INNER JOIN 
            Auditlog A ON I.AccountId = A.OtherId
      */

    INSERT INTO AuditlogDetails (AuditlogId, OldValue, NewValue)
        SELECT 
            A.AuditlogId, NULL, N'[{
            '+CASE WHEN i.NAME IS NOT NULL THEN '"Name": '+ i.NAME ELSE '' END+
            ' '+ CASE WHEN i.CompanyName IS NOT NULL THEN '"CompanyDetails" : '+ i.CompanyName ELSE '' END+
            ' '+ CASE WHEN i.ContactPhone IS NOT NULL THEN '"ContactPhone" : '+ i.ContactPhone ELSE '' END+
            ' '+ CASE WHEN i.[Status] IS NOT NULL THEN '"Status" : '+  CAST(i.[Status] AS VARCHAR(5)) ELSE '' END+''
        FROM 
            inserted i
        INNER JOIN 
            Auditlog A ON I.AccountId = A.OtherId
END
```

Comment: sr i want if Name not null and != '' then newvalue += "Name" : ' + ISNULL(i.NAME,'') +', else do not thing

Comment: if as your code name = null so my new value is [{ name : ''}] but i don't want add name when that value is null

Comment: let me give a try @beginerdeveloper

Comment: can i ask you a question in this case you using case when but should i change case when to if else. case when and if else which is more performance?

Comment: No. You can't apply a If Else in a Select query. And If Else performance better than a case is just a myth. @beginerdeveloper

Comment: i just want check more condition before i insert, for example i want to check new value and old value if that is different i will insert that record